# Activating Sheet that matches the value in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stuck with this situation. I have sheet names that is equivalent to the cell values below:

[image]

I'm now able to loop though the sheets. My problem is, how can I activate the sheet if it matches in the cell value? I have tried this code:

```
For Each sheet In Sheets
    If wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = sheet.Name Then
          'Activate the sheet
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me there's no need to loop and just go

```
On Error Resume Next
wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Activate
On Error GoTo 0
```

where the `On Error Resume Next` ... `On Error GoTo 0` statements handle the case there's no such sheet in `wb2`

Answer (score 0):

I have already figured out my problem:

```
For Each sheet In Sheets
If wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = sheet.Name Then
      sheet.Activate
End If
Next
```

Thanks!